# I can't see my ParsePush Notification on my android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, parse-server

I'm currently working on a chat application and I want to implement Parse Server Push notifications. I follow the documentation and put all the code that is required. My problem is that I can't see the notification, even though the console tells me that it was sent.

This is my MainActivity.java where is the Parse Installation.

```html
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        notificationsPush();
        createGraphicElements();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    
    private void notificationsPush(){
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    System.out.println("---------------------");
                    System.out.println("SUCCESS ON INSTALLATION");
                    System.out.println("----------------------");
                    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Chat", new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                System.out.println("----------------------");
                                System.out.println("SUCCESS ON CHANNEL");
                                System.out.println("----------------------");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("----------------------");
                                System.out.println("ERROR ON CHANNEL: " + e.getMessage());
                                System.out.println("CODE: " + e.getCode());
                                System.out.println("----------------------");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    System.out.println("---------------------");
                    System.out.println("ERROR ON INSTALLATION");
                    System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("CODE: " + e.getCode());
                    System.out.println("----------------------");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

These are my implementations on graddle module. (There is also the one that is required to connect to Firebase).

```html
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'


    //Parse Server
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.26.0"
    //PUSH Parse Server
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.26.0"
```

These are the functions that I use on my ParseCloud (they are on main.js).

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("SendPush", function(request) {


    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.exists("deviceToken");

    // here you can add other conditions e.g. to send a push to sepcific users or channel etc.

    var payload = {
      alert: request.params.Message
        // you can add other stuff here...
    };


    Parse.Push.send({
        data: payload,
        where: query
      }, {
        useMasterKey: true
      })
      .then(function() {
        response.success("Push Sent!");
      }, function(error) {
        response.error("Error while trying to send push " + error.message);
      });
});

Parse.Cloud.define("SendPush2", function(request) {
     var msg = request.params.Message;
     var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
     var user = request.params.user;
     query.equalTo("objectId", user);
     Parse.Push.send({
     where: query,
     data:{
          alert: {
               "title" : msg,
               "body" : msg
          },
          sound: 'default'
     }
     }, {
     useMasterKey: true,
     success: function(){
          response.success("Push Sent!");
     },
     error: function(error){
          response.error("Error while trying to send push " + error.message);
     }
     });
});

Parse.Cloud.define("SendPush3", function(request, response) {

var userId = request.params.user;
    var message = "sening a test message"; //request.params.message;
    var queryUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    queryUser.equalTo('objectId', userId);
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.matchesQuery('user', queryUser);

    Parse.Push.send({
      where: query,
      data: {
        alert: message,
        badge: 0,
        sound: 'default'
      }
    }, {
      success: function() {
        console.log('##### PUSH OK');
        response.success();
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log('##### PUSH ERROR');
        response.error('ERROR');
      },
      useMasterKey: true
    });
});
```

Finally, the piece of code of my app where I test those ParseCloud functions to send the notification.

```html
private void sendMessage(){
        if(messageEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            String messageToSend = messageEditText.getText().toString();
            messageEditText.setText("");

            MessageBO messageBO = new MessageBO();
            messageBO.setText(messageToSend);
            messageBO.setUserIdSender(idUser);
            messageBO.setUserIdReceiver(idContact);
            insertMessage(messageBO.getUserIdSender().toString(),
                          messageBO.getUserIdReceiver().toString(),
                          messageBO.getText().toString());
            enviarNotificacionPush(messageBO);
        }
        actualizarMensajes();
    }

private void sendNotificationPush(MessageBO m){
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Message", m.getText().toString());
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("SendPush",map, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("NOTIFICATION SUCCES: " + object);
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("ERROR ON NOTIFICATION PUSH: " + e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("CODE: " + e.getCode());
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                }
            }
        });

        HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("Message", m.getText().toString());
        map2.put("user", idUser);
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("SendPush2",map2, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("NOTIFICATION 2.0 SUCCESS: " + object);
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("ERROR ON NOTIFICATION PUSH 2.0: " + e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("CODE: " + e.getCode());
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                }
            }
        });
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("SendPush3",map2, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("NOTIFICACION 3.0 SUCCESS: " + object);
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("ERROR ON NOTIFICACION PUSH 3.0: " + e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("CODE: " + e.getCode());
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I use 3 functions that send notifications, all of them said that it was a success, but in my android emulator never arrive a notification. I check my parse Dashboard and even though that it says that the notifications were sent, it also says 0 deliveries. I need your help please because I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong.

If you need, the info of my Android emulator is the following:
[My android emulator info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt9TT.png)

[EDIT 1]
(I don't know how to refer the comment that ask me to do it but anyways) Because I see that maybe you'll need the installation class.
[installation class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fropf.png)
All installations are from the emulator due to I uninstall and install again the application. There is algo my smartphone, that is a Huawei (that also I can't see notifications but I know thats due to Huawei problems with google services).

[EDIT 2]Hello again, here is my Parse Server configuration(aka the `index.js` of my parse). I'm using the `parse_server_example` repository by the way.

```js
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

const express = require('express');
const ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
const path = require('path');
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
const args = process.argv || [];
const test = args.some(arg => arg.includes('jasmine'));

const databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}
const config = {
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://admin:123@localhost:27017/ParseServer?authSource=admin',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'MY_APP_ID',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MY_MASTER_KEY', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://192.168.10.100:1337/parse/', // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['Posts', 'Comments'], // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
  push: {
    android: {
      apiKey: 'AAAASP09btg:APA91bGxn3e0vJX0ri2DeFEWUjAODTCaP3mfCQ0la3oiIgNqNYUlj2THFlEwRjqnXGuI-8H_l5-0xZtyscn3yY4mRrAL5tNHYXrM8NBltgCwCx1gH8LFVvgAWubmV2Zsa5NkmD53vCeO'
    }
  }
};
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var configdashboard =  {
  "allowInsecureHTTP": true,
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "http://192.168.10.100:1337/parse/",
      "appId": "MY_APP_ID",
      "masterKey": "MY_MASTER_KEY",
      "appName": "ParseServer01"
    }
  ],"users": [
    {
      "user": "root",
      "pass": "123456"
    }
  ]
};
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard(configdashboard,{allowInsecureHTTP:configdashboard.allowInsecureHTTP});

const app = express();

app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
const mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
if (!test) {
  const api = new ParseServer(config);
  app.use(mountPath, api);
}

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
if (!test) {
  const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
  httpServer.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
  });
  // This will enable the Live Query real-time server
  ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
}

module.exports = {
  app,
  config,
};
```

[EDIT 3] Hello again, I was trying to send notifications with curl and this is what happens:

```
curl -X POST \
```

> ```
> -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: wPacsFQMmP" \
> -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: DwonoEbeNf" \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> -d '{
>       "where": {
>         "deviceType": {
>           "$in": [
>             "android"
>           ]
>         }
>       },
>       "data": {
>         "title": "The Shining",
>         "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."
>       }
>     }'\   http://192.168.10.100:1337/parse/push
> ```

{"result":true}[

Also as additional info, when I try making a push using FCM only (that means, follow this [Firebase FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=1)) and the result is basically the same, it says it was sent succesfully but I don't see it on the android emulator, not even in my old smartphone (Nokia 6).

[EDIT 4] I turn on verbose, and this is what I found in my parse logs about SendPush cloud function.

```
REQUEST for [POST] /parse/push: {\\n  \\\"channels\\\": [\\n    \\\"SignChat\\\"\\n  ],\\n  \\\"data\\\": {\\n    \\\"alert\\\": \\\"The Giants won against the Mets 2-3.\\\"\\n  }\\n}\",\n      \"method\": \"POST\",\n      \"timestamp\": \"2021-10-28T20:25:27.623Z\",\n      \"url\": \"/parse/push\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"level\": \"verbose\",\n      \"message\": \"RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/functions/SendPush: {\\n  \\\"response\\\": {}\\n}\",\n      \"result\": {\n        \"response\": {}\n      },\n      \"timestamp\": \"2021-10-28T20:25:27.619Z\"\n    }
```

Comment: Would you mind to share what you see on your installation class?

Comment: do you mean the class that got the ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation() ?

Comment: It'd be better to check on your dashboard.

Comment: Hello, I put an image of my Parse Dashboard installations on EDIT 1

Comment: `SendPush2` will not work because you can't query on Installation class using a user id. `SendPush3` will not work because you don't have a `user` pointer on your Installation class. `SendPush` should work though. What do you see on your logs, cloud code response, and push status when you use it?

Comment: The logs about the cloud functions says:
2021-10-14T00:46:54.786Z - Ran cloud function SendPush3 for user 4GdpFdWgua with:
  Input: {"Mensaje":"help","user":"4GdpFdWgua"}
  Result: undefined
2021-10-14T00:46:54.764Z - Ran cloud function SendPush2 for user 4GdpFdWgua with:
  Input: {"Mensaje":"help","user":"4GdpFdWgua"}
  Result: undefined
2021-10-14T00:46:54.746Z - Ran cloud function SendPush for user 4GdpFdWgua with:
  Input: {"Mensaje":"help"}
  Result: undefined

And push status says the target was one of my users `objectId` and succesful deliveries 0.

Comment: Could you please confirm that your app is running on background at the moment you are sending the push?

Comment: Yes, I always send notifications with the Parse server running on a linux virtual machine (red hat).

Comment: I mean the Android app. It needs to be running on background of the emulator in order to receive the push notification.

Comment: Ahh yes, the android app is running on background of the emulator.

Comment: Have you checked your Parse Server logs for any details about the unsuccessful deliveries? You should see something over there.

Comment: Well, when I see one of my past pushes, it says **Push Opens: N/A** , **Push Sends: 0**. In target it says: **Grouping: objectId** , **Operator: is** , **Value: [one of my users objectId]**. Then it say delivery report where it says succesful deliveries 0.

Comment: It would be good to check the logs you have on Parse Server and/or access the Push Status collection directly in mongodb.

Comment: How I do that? I have Robo3t in order to control my Mongo Database but I don't see that Push Status Collection.

Comment: How are you running Parse Server? Would you mind to share the settings you are using? On MongoDB the collection name should be _PushStatus

Comment: Hi, I put an edit (EDIT 2) where I share the settings of my parse server. I also was trying to check that _PushStatus collection on my mongo but If I try db._PushStatus.find() it says: **uncaught exception: TypeError: db._PushStatus is undefined :
@(shell):1:1** . Even though, I can see the collection on Robo3t and all notifications status says *succeded* but with **numSent : 0**

Comment: `db.getCollection('_PushStatus').find()` should work. No more details other than the numSent: 0? Did you manage to check parse server logs? Did you only try using the emulator? Would you mind to also try with a device?

Comment: I tried with my old Nokia 6, which in another android project where I also used parse push notifications it worked out. I use the same configurations in this project and I tested again with my nokia but still dont show nothing. Parse logs still says the same thing that before.

Comment: Were you able to manage to see Parse Server logs (not push status)?

Comment: Well if you mean the Logs section in the parse dashboard, yes.

Comment: Yes, those logs should be enough. No useful information over there? Are you running Parse Server with `verbose: true` option?

Comment: Hi, I use verbose and I put one of the parse logs in EDIT 4.

Answer (score 0):

To send push notifications for Android devices, the required fields are `deviceToken` and `GCMSenderID`.

However, according to the screenshot you sent, the GCMSenderId of your installations is empty, and it's required for sending push notifications.

In your `MainActivity`, you're not explicitly set it, which is needed to save it properly.

Here's a sample code showing how you can do that:

```
 ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("GCMSenderId", INSERT_YOUR_SENDER_ID);
    installation.saveInBackground();
```

Once both fields are filled, the push notification might work properly.

Comment: I used this code and it register the sender ID on the field. However, still doesn't show up.

Comment: What are your results from the dashboard? Did you set your FCM credentials on the server-side?

Comment: It says that the result of the Parse Cloud functions that I use to send notificactions is undefined. Yes, I put the FCM api key on the server. I'm starting to think that maybe there is a problem with some php codes I put on the project.